# http client vertx in unix

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm getting an issue when running vertx on a Unix server. When full message is received the end handler does not work.

```
HttpClientRequest request = client.post (8580, "localhost", "/", response -> 
{

  if (response.statusCode () == 200) {
    response.handler (t -> {

        LOG.info ("RECEIVE DATA: " + t.toString ());

    });
    response.endHandler (t -> {
        LOG.info ("endHandler: DONE"); //DO NOT PRINT ON LOG FILE
    });

  } else {
    LOG.info  ("Sent error:"+response.statusMessage ());
  }
});
```

My source demo: https://github.com/blueskyvn/vertx_client.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should close your HTTP client after request is completed. So, move `client.close();` line to the response handler.
2. Move your entire code for working with HTTP client to the verticle. You can just move it to your `HttpVerticle` class and call it after server is started. Use [listen](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServer.html#listen-io.vertx.core.Handler-) method with callback.

Comment: thanks your suggestion. This project is a demo to describe my error on a Unix server